# how to iterate over multiple "div" with certain class, and stop when class changes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, loops

Questions says it all but in a few line..
I've got HTML page which looks like this

```html
             ...
<div class="line-up" .. > .. </>
<div class="line-down" ..> .. </>
<div class="line-down" ..> .. </>
<div class="line-down" ..> .. </>
            ...
<div class="line-up" ..> .. </>
<div class="line-down" ..> .. </>
```

I want to be able to iterate through each `<div class="line-down">` belonging to one `<div class="line-up">`
and go on with the next `<div class="line-down"..>`  .
I can already iterate through each `<div class="line-up">` with :

```
for first_line in soup.findAll("div",class_="line-up"):
```

But I just can't find what to do to iterate with the next div and stopping at a point.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are the `<div class="line-down">` elements children of the `<div class="line-up">` elements? Your description seems to indicate so, but your HTML sample doesn't.

Comment: No they are not. they are siblings of line-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, get all div tags-- `findAll("div")`, dont worry about the class.  Then, iterate through your results, and if `class=="line-down"`, break.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just how can I test the class of a div with beautifulsoup ? EDIT  : is that how ? =)  "if (div["class"]=="stylelistrow"):"

Comment: @Nikkolasg Yeah, that's one way to do it.  there's also an attrs  method.